# Share kit integration into iOS - Dropbox Authentication on button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api, sharekit

I’m trying to adapt the original Sharekit demo app so that it allows me to authenticate dropbox on a single button press (instead of appearing a new view etc. like it does in the demo).

To do this I have wired up a button with the following method as the IBAction (in the initial ViewController it launches into on Storyboard):

```
-(IBAction)assignDropbox:(id)sender 
{
    [SHK setRootViewController:self];

    Class sharerClass = NSClassFromString(@"SHKDropbox");

    BOOL isiOSSharer = [sharerClass isSubclassOfClass:[SHKiOSSharer class]];

    if ([sharerClass isServiceAuthorized]) {

        if (isiOSSharer) {

            [sharerClass getUserInfo];

             UIAlertView *iosSharerAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iOS Social.framework sharer"
             message:@"You can deauthorize this kind of sharer in settings.app, not here. By tapping this button you have refetched user info data only."
             delegate:nil
             cancelButtonTitle:nil
             otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
             [iosSharerAlert show];

        } else {

            [sharerClass logout];
            //[self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    } else {

        SHKSharer *sharer = [[sharerClass alloc] init];
        [sharer authorize];

        if (isiOSSharer) {
            UIAlertView *iosSharerAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iOS Social.framework sharer"
             message:@"You can authorize this kind of sharer in settings.app, not here."
             delegate:nil
             cancelButtonTitle:nil
             otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
             [iosSharerAlert show];
        }
    }


    if ([sharerClass isServiceAuthorized]) {
        NSLog(@"After Logging in Username: %@", [sharerClass username]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"After Logging in Username: %@", [sharerClass username]);
    }
}
```

I’ve added the following notification code ViewDidLoad of the ViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(authDidFinish:)
                                             name:@"SHKAuthDidFinish"
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(sendDidCancel:)
                                             name:@"SHKSendDidCancel"
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(sendDidStart:)
                                             name:@"SHKSendDidStartNotification"
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(sendDidFinish:)
                                             name:@"SHKSendDidFinish"
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(sendDidFailWithError:)
                                             name:@"SHKSendDidFailWithError"
                                           object:nil];
```

With the following code within the actual main (to make the notifications actually work - as per setup):

```
- (void)authDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
NSNumber *success = [userInfo objectForKey:@"success"];

if (NO == [success boolValue]) {
    NSLog(@"authDidFinish: NO");
} else {
    NSLog(@"authDidFinish: YES");
    NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", userInfo);
}

}

- (void)sendDidCancel:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"sendDidCancel:");
}

- (void)sendDidStart:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"sendDidStart:");
}

- (void)sendDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"sendDidFinish:");
}

- (void)sendDidFailWithError:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"sendDidFailWithError:");
}'
```

It launches the web view in the app, and I can authenticate (I get notifications from dropbox saying another device has logged on), however the save authentication/session code in ‘SHKDropbox.m’ is never called.
Method under:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedAccountInfo:(DBAccountInfo*)info
```

I’ve done a lot of comparison work to see what the differences are between the projects, but can’t see any difference in settings.
Have you got any storyboard/button presses sample code as described above. Or have you got any idea on why this isn’t working on ShareKit?

Comment: I can't speak to the Sharekit side of this, but `loadedAccountInfo` only fires in response to calling the  `loadAccountInfo` method, but I don't see `loadAccountInfo` in your code anywhere.

Comment: Sharekit may call that for you though, but make sure you implement `loadAccountInfoFailedWithError` as well, in case there's an error.